# If $f$ is a real valued measurable function in $[0, \infty)$ which is uniformly cont. and $f \in L^{1}([0,\infty))$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is a real  valued measurable function in $[0, \infty)$ which is uniformly continuous and $f \in L^{1}([0,\infty))$ then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$$
Here measurable is in the Lebesgue sense.
Can anyone give an outline of its proof?

Edit: I forgot to mention the function has to be uniformly continuous.
Otherwise just take $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^{2}}$

Comment: That would be hard to prove a false statement...